# Help with coreless micromotor. Can I add a switch?

Tags: motor, switches

I have ordered some coreless micromotors, as shown [here](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/5-x-DIY-DC-1-5-6V-50000RPM-Electric-Coreless-Mini-Vibration-Motor-for-Toys-/121453903026?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item1c47377cb2).

These are for a science club for the kids to tinker around with. We are simply using them to make lightweight cardboard junk robots jiggle about (by taping them on). The motors are wired up to a 2xAAA battery pack.

I have two questions:

1) can I add a switch to this rudimentary circuit? Tactile switches would be ideal. I don't have a circuit board so I am not really understanding if this is possible with the pin system I have seen on most switches (such as [these](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/190836677659?tfrom=190837185497&tpos=unknow&ttype=price&talgo=origal).)

2) Can I protect the very delicate wiring in the back of these motors? I have easily broken one just with lightweight playing. The kids will be a little more heavy handed.  I am thinking a blob of resin glue? Is there any reason not to do this?

Comment: Tack switches are mostly momentary. They have to be pressed for the motor to be on,  and stay pressed for the motor to stay on. You need a toggle or slide switch if you want them to stay on.

Comment: And these kinds of toy simple robots are called bristle bugs.

Answer (score 1):

#### Wires:

If you do use glue, thick glue only. Thin glue, such as instan/power glue will seep into the body very easily.

Best to have a 2mm long ring of good quality heat-shrink (e.g. polyolefin if composition is given).

Fold the leads onto the body, push the heat-shrink around it (there should be enough free room to achieve this easily, so don't buy it too small).

Shrink with hot air (not a flame or soldering iron!), such as a household hair-dryer on maximum.

If need be, fold the wires back and add another ring.

A lightly flexible fold-back connection is better than a hard-glue one, since the wires will snap at the glue edge just as easily.

#### Switch:

You can wire these up with normal wires and glue them onto a surface. Should be easy enough. Do watch out that two leads will be connected together on each side.

Most likely a pair that is lightly bent towards each other is hard-connected and the switch only connects the two sets together.

So it very probably looks a bit like this on the inside:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpqvl7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But, always measure/test to be sure.

### EDIT:

And be careful with the leads, they are a little fragile, so if you flip-flop around with wires a lot before you glue them down (or such) they may break.

There are also tactile switches that you can screw into a surface, but maybe that's too much DIY-ing to then mount that surface to something?:

[One eBay Example](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Panel-Mounted-Round-Head-Momentary-SPST-2-Pin-Push-Button-Switch-x10-/321336871836?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4ad12b8b9c)

[Another eBay Example](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10PCS-12mm-Panel-Mount-12v-RED-MOMENTARY-OFF-ON-Push-Button-HORN-Switch-B170-/191627980352?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2c9deaee40)

[And another one (The 12V is just "this is only for low voltage", 3V is fine too)](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Mini-Push-Button-SPST-Momentary-N-O-OFF-ON-Switch-10mm-Red-12V-MVS1-/261803017751)

They are also available for buying at DigiKey, Farnell, etc as "Panel Mount Momentary Switches" or other such words, in case links become invalid (probably soon)

Comment: The polyolefin will mostly likely be out of budget. Do you think a layer of plasticy sellotape will achieve the same? I guess as you say hot glue from a glue gun, although thick will cause a hard edge too. I will try both out. Thank you for this detail. Much appreciated.

Comment: @jksl 1m of 10mm polyolefin should not cost more than a couple € even at an extortionary hobby shop (or I'm a purchasing genius, that's possible too). You can certainly use tape, but it will peel more easily, be more easily movable, etc. I have to admit my brain keeps jumping back to solutions I'd employ in the field, which is good, but not for working with a budget.